# button click event fires on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a js and htlm code in jfiddle.

I have created the button onclick event on the object method and on the page load it firing the event.
Is this some problem with my code.

```js
var user = {
  data: [
    {name: 'T. Woods', age: 37},
    {name: 'P. Mickelson', age: 43}
  ],
  clickHandler: function (event) {
    console.log(this);
    var randomNum = ((Math.random() * 2 | 0) + 1) - 1; // Random number between 0 and 1
    $('input').val(this.data[randomNum].name + ' ' + this.data[randomNum].age);
  }
};

console.log(user);
$('button').click(user.clickHandler(this));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Homepage Headline</h1>
  <div id="div1">
    <p>
      <button>Get Random Person</button><br>
      <input type="text">
    </p>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="oops.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you link the code ? Else we would not be able to help you

Comment: Please copy all relevant code in to the question

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bjtoawrv/1/

Comment: Please don't circumvent the rules. Just do what you're asked to do.

Comment: do not skip the block about fiddle and code by posting the link as code. Post the code as text directly in the question. YOu can create a fiddle here by using the <> button

Answer (score 4):

Your click event listener needs to be a function otherwise it will trigger `.click()` on the button instead of creating a listener

See the documentation for [`.click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/)

```
$("button").click(function () {
   user.clickHandler(this)
});
```

Test it with your code here -

```js
var user = {
 data :[
 {name: "T. Woods", age:37},
 {name: "P. Mickelson", age:43}
 ],
 clickHandler:function (event) {
  console.log(this);
 var randomNum = ((Math.random () * 2 | 0) + 1) - 1; // random number between 0 and 1
 //console.log(this.data[randomNum].name + " " + this.data[randomNum].age);
  // This line is adding a random person from the data array to the text field
  $ ("input").val (this.data[randomNum].name + " " + this.data[randomNum].age);
 }
};
console.log(user);
$("button").click(function() {
  user.clickHandler(this)
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Homepage Headline</h1>
  <div id="div1">
    <p>           
        <button>Get Random Person</button><br>
         <input type="text">
      </p>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="oops.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks but my problem is click event firing on page load. Can you explain it more.

Comment: [`.click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) expects a callback function, but by adding `(this)` you're invoking the function immediately

Comment: If this answer has helped you, please consider 'accepting' it; This will mark your question as solved, and also reward both you and the answerer some reputation - [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because you invoke the `user.clickhandler()` function when the page loads and set its response as the click handler for the element.

You instead want to provide the *reference* to the function to the event handler. You will also need to `bind()` the scope of `user` to the reference, as that's what `clickhandler()` expects to run under. Try this:

```
$("button").click(user.clickHandler.bind(user));
```

Working example:

```js
var user = {
  data: [{
    name: "T. Woods",
    age: 37
  }, {
    name: "P. Mickelson",
    age: 43
  }],
  clickHandler: function(event) {
    console.log(this);
    var randomNum = ((Math.random() * 2 | 0) + 1) - 1; 
    $("input").val(this.data[randomNum].name + " " + this.data[randomNum].age);
  }
};
$("button").click(user.clickHandler.bind(user));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Homepage Headline</h1>
<div id="div1">
  <p>
    <button>Get Random Person</button><br>
    <input type="text">
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: can you explain more without bind what is happning?

Comment: `bind()` sets the scope that the function will run under. Because you expect `this` in the `clickHandler` to be the `user` object (and not the `button` element as it would be in a standard jQuery event handler) you have to manually change the scope, hence: `bind()`

Comment: My problem is why user.clickHandler funciton running on page load it should run on the button click.

Comment: I know. I described the problem and gave you a solution in the above answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to attach the handler, not call it, and then bind the `this` object accordingly:

```
user.clickHandler.bind(user)
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not a problem, you call

```
$("button").click(user.clickHandler(this));
```

at the loading, then it call the click event

Replace it by

```
$("button").bind("click", user.clickHandler(this));
```

Comment: He just have to remove that to fix it @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: it should run on button click not on load.

Comment: this dose not fix my problem still button click event run on page load.

Comment: I would suggest you test your code, as it does not do what the OP requests, nor does it work as you describe

Comment: I am not looking for the solution. looking for why on page load click event is firing?

Comment: @devendrasingh Because you call $("button").click(), and .click() is a function that fire the click event.
You call in the root of your script, then on page load